# Laravel losing session after redirect to paypal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm havig problem with keeping login session on my site after redirect to paypal. 
Please help me i'm losing my mind.
Here is my config/session.php file

```
driver' => 'native',


'lifetime' => 0,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue once while redirecting from site to provider and back. I had set the session for the user on non-www domain.com, and the provider was redirecting back to the www. domain. For the full story, see here:

[PHP Session not being stored by Firefox after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458776/php-session-not-being-stored-by-firefox-after-redirect/13462400#13462400)